# Creating a new dataframe column based on the values in another column of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I am analysing a dataset containing steps taking during walkouts. I have information on the particular week of the year each walkout occurred. But I want to add the location of the walkout. For instance, if the week of the year is 30, then the walkout occurred in Ilorin, if it is 32, then the walkout occurred in osogbo.

I tried using the apply function.
To do this, I created a list containing the week numbers, then I defined a function to check if the column value is in that list. If yes, the function should return 'Ilorin', and if no, the function should return 'osogbo'.

The resulting column showed all values to be osogbo and none was Ilorin.

Comment: Please, share your code.

Comment: 4. Adding work location using apply to apply a custom function 
work_week = [31,32,40,42,43,46,48]
def work_locate(week_of_year):
    if week_of_year in work_week:
        return 'ilorin'
    else:
        return 'osogbo'
steps_22['work_location'] = steps_22['week_of_year'].map(work_locate)

Comment: Please, edit your question with your code correctly formatted. Also, provide a minimal reproductible example, so that people can help you correctly.

Comment: Thanks. The issues is now resolved. The code was correct, as I later discovered. It was my system that was acting up.